# Zip over iterables in both positional and keyword arguments

Tags: python, python-itertools, keyword-argument

#### Question

I have a function `func`, and a set of positional and keyword arguments (`args` and `kwargs`). Some unknown number of these arguments are iterables of a particular type (`SpecialType`), each of the same length. I would like to simultaneously iterate over all of these special iterables side-by-side, and apply `func` to just the set of corresponding values in those iterables, whilst also passing in the other function arguments every time. In pseudocode what I want might look roughly like this:

```py
from itertools import repeat

args_all_as_iterables = [a.iterable if isinstance(a, SpecialType) else repeat(a) for a in args]
kwargs_all_as_iterables = {k: v.iterable if isinstance(v, SpecialType) else repeat(v) for k, v in kwargs}

for args_values, kwarg_values in zip(*args_all_as_iterables, **kwargs_all_as_iterables):
    this_result = func(*args_values, **kwargs_values)
```

The code above is obviously not valid (`zip` won't accept the unpacked kwargs), but I do not know how to zip together both positional arguments and keyword arguments like this. (The purpose of `itertools.repeat` here is to allow me to zip over every single argument together, just repeating the non-iterable arguments as many times as necessary.)

---

#### Attempts

If all I had to do was apply the func to multiple iterables then I would do something like

```py
for values in zip(*[a.iterable for a in args]):
    result = func(*[v for v in values])
```

but I don't see how to generalize this to accept kwargs too.

I could try to turn `kwargs` into a list of iterators of `(key, value)` tuples? I could try making a separate list which records which arguments in `args`, `kwargs` are of `SpecialType`? Ideally I would like a way to zip over both the list of args and the dictionary of kwargs though.

---

#### Context

The context is that `SpecialType` is a `Tree` class which contains multiple datasets. Instead of `a.iterable` I am actually calling `tree.subtree`, which returns an iterator over all data nodes in the tree. The `zip` is meant to allow me to simultaneously walk along the nodes of an arbitrary number of side-by-side trees, applying `func` to the data in the corresponding nodes of each tree simultaneously. I will then store the various results of calling `func` on each set of tree nodes and use it to build a new tree. See [this issue](https://github.com/TomNicholas/datatree/issues/29) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You can treat `kwargs.values()` the same as args.

Answer (score 0):

My solution, in its actual original context looks like this:

```py
# Walk all trees simultaneously, applying func to all nodes that lie in same position in different trees
# We don't know which arguments are DataTrees so we zip all arguments together as iterables
args_as_tree_length_iterables = [a.subtree if isinstance(a, DataTree) else repeat(a) for a in args]
n_args = len(args_as_tree_length_iterables)
kwargs_as_tree_length_iterables = {k: v.subtree if isinstance(v, DataTree) else repeat(v) for k, v in kwargs.items()}
for all_node_args in zip(*args_as_tree_length_iterables, *list(kwargs_as_tree_length_iterables.values())):
    node_args_as_datasets = [a.ds if isinstance(a, DataTree) else a for a in all_node_args[:n_args]]
    node_kwargs_as_datasets = dict(zip([k for k in kwargs_as_tree_length_iterables.keys()],
                                       [v.ds if isinstance(v, DataTree) else v for v in all_node_args[n_args:]]))

    # Now we can call func on the data in this particular set of corresponding nodes
    results = func(*node_args_as_datasets, **node_kwargs_as_datasets)
```